What words are banned in titles?
I was doing an edit for a question and was about to save when I got the error

Title cannot contain 'xxx'

I tried to find an official list, and came across a couple of meta questions, but none of them gave an absolute list, only a couple of words that are banned, or the regex expression that is used. Does SO have reference material for banned words?

In order to prevent people from just working around the restrictions, rather than writing meaningful titles, the details of those types of restrictions are not made public.

From my experience: if the xxx part is showing you the whole title, it really means your title is too short. And, yes, there are tons of old questions that would not pass today's filters.

@Makyen, I was wondering why, thanks for letting me know!

I admit, I do wish the error was a bit more descriptive than "cannot contain"; it doesn't promote users to write a good title (I see far to many get around the system by adding tags to the title or adding typographical errors). Something like "Title does not meet minimum requirements; it may be too short or not descriptive. See [ask] for tips on how to give your question a good title."

Just a question: if some words are forbidden in the title, is there also a check for simple workarounds, like "p_o_r_n" or "p0rn" instead of "porn", "b1nge-watch1ng" instead of "binge-watching", ...?

@Dominique     No .

@TylerH: would that be useful? In case yes, I might write a feature-request for it.

@Dominique Maybe, but it's also going to be an unending cat-and-mouse game. Any "alternatives" that get blocked will also get replaced with other creative spellings.

The exact details of the content blocklist for titles are not public. The intent being to prevent people from doing lazy things to work around it without honouring the spirit of the block rules. (this answer is paraphrased from Makyen's comment under the question post).

In this case I don't really believe that though, as the error message still spills the beans. Don't use XXX. So to make the error go away, which is absolutely not the same thing as putting thought into what a proper title is, just don't put XXX. The error message as it is, is designed to help you be lazy.
